# increase/change mavros local_position pose publish frequency

Tags: ros, pose, ros-melodic, mavros, frequency

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I increase or change the mavros/local_position/pose publishing frequency? (Default only 30Hz)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361371/increase/change-mavros-local_position-pose-publish-frequency/) by [noob_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/58294/noob_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @noob_ros,

As @Root3287 said, you can try to dive into the code and search the correct line in which you can change the rate at which the node is publishing, however I do not recommend that in any case. Since the developers have included some options to change this rate.

You can execute in a terminal the command: `rosrun mavros mavsys rate --all frq` beign `frq` the target rate you want (E.g.: `rosrun mavros mavsys rate --all 50`). With that command, you will change all the topics update rate. If you want to know more about this you can use the help argument: `rosrun mavros mavsys rate -h`.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2022-05-19**:
it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may not apply in general, but it is possible that the pose is published at 1Hz if the `MAV_1_MODE` parameter is set to `Normal`. Changing it to `Onboard` will allow to publish at a much higher frequency.

> Edit the parameter from QGroundControl.

---

Originally posted by [Lucas2903](https://answers.ros.org/users/70408/lucas2903/) with karma: 11 on 2021-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1